# Clear MKSnapshotter memory

Tags: ios, memory, mkmapsnapshotter

Im currently using the `MKSnapshotter` but I noticed (similar to MKMapView) that it holds on to a high memory consumption and never releases it for the duration of the app. I've tried releasing the memory but no use:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self releaseMKMapSnapshotMem];
}

-(void)releaseMKMapSnapshotMem{
    self.snapshotter=nil;//MKSnapShotter
    self.options=nil;//MKSnapShotterOptions
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Includes more detail

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions * snapOptions= [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
        self.options=snapOptions;
        CLLocation * salonLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.lat longitude:self.long];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 300, 300);
        self.options.region = region;
        self.options.size = self.view.frame.size;
        self.options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

        MKMapSnapshotter * mapSnapShot = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:self.options];
        self.snapshotter =mapSnapShot;
        [self.snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
                return;
            }

            UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
            self.mapImage = image;
            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

            [self saveMapDataToCache:data WithKey:mapName];



        }];
```

Comment: what's your mapView property declaration look like? Weak/strong?  Might need a weak ...

Comment: @meierjo its weak already

Comment: Little more info?  i.e. A ViewCOntroller is presented with a mapView, user saves location, app takes a snapshot, saves it, then dismisses the ViewController - etc...

Comment: @meierjo ViewController is presented, latitude and longitude is passed in the `MKSnapShotter` to take the image, the image then is cached.

Comment: @meierjo see above for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    MKMapSnapshotOptions * snapOptions= [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
    CLLocation * salonLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.lat longitude:self.long];
    //location.coordinate or salonLocation.coordinate below????
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 300, 300);
    snapOptions.region = region;
    snapOptions.size = self.view.frame.size;
    snapOptions.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    MKMapSnapshotter * mapSnapShot = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions: snapOptions];
    [mapSnapShot startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
            return;
        }
        UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        [self saveMapDataToCache:data WithKey:mapName];

    }];
```

I'm doing pretty much the same as you're doing with only two differences:

```
    options.region = _mapView.region;
    options.size = _mapView.frame.size;
```

my _mapView is the map being displayed in the view controller...

Comment: Im not displaying a map, im only displaying the snap shot, if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you fired up Instruments to track heap growth?  google/search SO for many excellent tuts on Instruments